# Using Instagram Programmatically on Android

Tags: android, social-networking

Is there any way I can post on instagram programmatically in Android?
I want to post Photos and status text on Instagram.

Comment: official doc: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 0):

if Instagram allow their android application to receive requests from other applications via intents then yes. You need to check Instagram documenation. I had a quick look and I can see some iphone hooks but nothing for Android but check in detail as I may have missed it.

Alternately use their API.